# Watching for changes on specific key in Consul using OrbitzWorld's consul-client

Tags: java, key-value, watch, consul

We are in a process of migrating from [Zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) to [Consul](https://www.consul.io) for managing dynamic key-value configuration. We are using [OrbitzWorldwide client](https://github.com/OrbitzWorldwide/consul-client) and we would like to use its watch capabilities for subscribing to key-value changes. However, we are not sure how to do this.

Zookeeper has native support for watches. For example:

```
curator.getData()
    .usingWatcher(watcher)
    .forPath(path);
```

In OrbitzWorldwide's client there is the KVCache object which support listeners, but one of the required parameters is **watchSeconds** and it's not clear what happens when timeout reaches? Should we subscribe again?

Sample code using OrbitzWorldwide's client:

```
KVCache kvCache = KVCache.newCache(consul.keyValueClient(), path, watchSeconds);
kvCache.addListener(new ConsulCache.Listener<String, Value>() {
        public void notify(Map<String, Value> map) {
            // Key changed
        }
});
kvCache.start();
```

Is there anyone here with experience in this library that can tell us how we can use it to watch for changes on a key? Can you recommend some other client with better support for watches?

Answer (score 4):

Well, after checking with the developers at [OrbitzWorldwide](https://github.com/OrbitzWorldwide/consul-client/issues/186), the client is responsible for re-initiating the call once **watchSeconds** timeout reaches. Tested and works as expected.

The watch is based on Consul's [blocking HTTP API](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http.html) which simply means that the call is blocked until key is changed or timeout reaches. [OrbitzWorldwide](https://github.com/OrbitzWorldwide/consul-client/issues/186)'s client will handle these blocking calls for us.